# mongoDB GUI that supports the new mongodb authentication system

Tags: mongodb

is there a mongoDB GUI that supports mongo 2.6+ authentication?

I have a mongoDB 3.0.3 server and can't manage it with robomongo anymore. I also tried MongoHub with no luck :(

I want to access from a MacOS

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find a GUI that actually supports mongodb driver 3.0.3. Should I reformulate the question or remove it?

Comment: Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: My two cents: A GUI is *in no way* going to help you with administering MongoDB, which requires a bit of knowledge, which can't be replaced with a GUI. Use the `mongo` shell, which is available both via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) and [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and dig into the MongoDB docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try MongoChef. It's free for non-commercial and personal using. It seems good.

http://3t.io/mongochef/download/platform/

Answer (score 0):

Try MongoBooster. Essential MongoDB Admin GUI.

http://mongobooster.com

Disclaimer, I am one of developers of MongoBooster.

Answer (score 0):

I use "adminMongo" which supports latest MongoDB version.

https://github.com/mrvautin/adminMongo

Please raise any issues in Github.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I've just released [Mongoclient](https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient) which supports OSx, Linux and Windows as well as mobile platforms, since it's written in meteorJS.

By the way it's completely free and open-source.